# Get data from two different tables

Tags: python

I have 2 tables in a server. One table has the "name" data and the other table has the "sales" data and I need to show both on one screen.
I need to use the following code to get both data from different tables. I'm using Python-SQL. Here is what I got:

```py
def display_records():
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM sales, products")
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    msg = ""
    for record in records:
        msg += f"Name: {record[0]}, sales: {record[2]}\n"
    text_widget.delete('1.0', tk.END)
    text_widget.insert(tk.END, msg)
```

Comment: How are the two tables related?  Do the sales have a product number?  You need to link the tables somehow.

Comment: Yes, they are linked by the productID. ProductID is PK on product's table and sales' tables has the productID FK. sales' table has "PK" as Primary Key

Comment: What is your question about this?

Answer (score -1):

```
def display_records():
    cursor.execute("SELECT products.name, sales.sales FROM products JOIN sales ON products.name = sales.name")
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    msg = ""
    for record in records:
        msg += f"Name: {record[0]}, sales: {record[1]}\n"
    text_widget.delete('1.0', tk.END)
    text_widget.insert(tk.END, msg)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).